# My Marie gold plant is drying up

Tags: houseplants, flowers

I brought a Marie gold plant and I kept it in sunlight ,I water it twice a day ... But it seem that leaves and buds are drying up .. I even cut a dry leaves a week before ...but still it continues drying...I can see that the buds are flowered soon such that they are even small.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean marigold (though your plant looks a little tall to be one of those) or a different plant? what soil is in the pot and how big is the pot (can't see all of the pot in the image)?

Comment: The soil looks dry.  A larger pot would be much better to provide moisture control. I think even once a day water requirement means the pot is too small.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the comments and a little research I have learnt that a Marie Gold is an actual plant. Apologies I thought it was a typo at first. It is not a true Marigold but is a good companion plant similar to marigolds.

From the images it would appear that the soil is very dry. Do you have any stones or pebbles below the soil to store water in, this could help. I usually but a layer of stones below the soil when I plant flowers.

Could you try placing the plant pot on a saucer or tray of water to help keep the soil moist.

Answer (score 0):

Your plant is dehydrated beyond its thirst. Marigolds are native to tropics, and they thrive in moist and warm and humid environment. Your issue is a either of two or both:-
1.) Underwatering.
2.) Cultivating marigold on higher altitudes where the excess cold and dry weather can cause the plants to dry out by transpiration.

Also, try moving it indoors in a place where direct sunlight will fall through it and it benefits from heat. Thus, it'll be insulated from excess cold and dry weather as also will be subject to high humidity indoors.

Bonus point: More sunlight = more carotenoids= darker orange hues on marigolds, oranges, mandarins and so on.